# Cocoa - Animating reordering of NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, sorting, animation, nsoutlineview

How would I go about animating the reordering of an `NSOutlineView` at the click of a button? High-level step-by-step instructions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If someone could help I'm looking for the same...

Comment: I just ended up using a WebView for my project.

Comment: The new view-based NSOutlineView that ships with Lion has some new methods that automatically animate reordering.

Comment: Alec: That's probably an answer enough. Thanks!